# Unable to remotely run node from launchfile with launch machine tag

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

- My remote machine is running Ubuntu 18.04 on a ARM64 architecture and ROS has been cross compiled and the node I want to run is included there.
  On the remote machine I run my node like this :

`source /home/nvidia/crosscompiled/ros/install_isolated/setup.bash && rosrun sekonix_camera_ut sekonix_camera_ut_node`

On the remote the env variables `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` are set and I can get the images from the remote node on my local machine with no problem.

- My local machine is running Ubuntu 18.04 on a AMD64 architecture. Ros has been installed with APT and I have one package in my workspace : `platform`.

The local's machine ssh key is installed on the remote and I can ssh without password into the remote.

I want to be able to run the node directly from the local machine. So I made this launchfile :

```
<launch>
  <machine name="remote_machine"
           address="192.168.100.200"
           user="user"
           env-loader="/home/nvidia/crosscompiled/ros/install_isolated/setup.sh"
  />
  <node pkg="sekonix_camera_ut" type="sekonix_camera_ut_node" name="sekonix_camera_ut" />
</launch>
```

But when run the launchfile I get this error :

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [sekonix_camera_ut/sekonix_camera_ut_node]: sekonix_camera_ut
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [124]=/home/maxandre/catkin_pkg/src/tf_shifter
ROS path [125]=/home/maxandre/catkin_pkg/src/platform
ROS path [132]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem ? Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377006/unable-to-remotely-run-node-from-launchfile-with-launch-machine-tag/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2021-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How I solved my problem :

- I added the attribute `machine` to the `node`  tag :

  ```
    <node machine="nvidia_drive" pkg="sekonix_camera_ut" type="sekonix_camera_ut_node" name="sekonix_camera_ut" />
  ```
- I had set the to my remote in the hosts file (The hostname has to be the same as the remote's hostname):

  ```
    #/etc/hosts local
    192.168.100.200 tegra-ubuntu
  ```
- I had tp update paramiko on the local :

  ```
    sudo pip install paramiko --upgrade
  ```
- I had to set the ROS env variables on the host :

  ```
    export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.100.100
    export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.100.100:11311
  ```
- I had to make sure that the ssh server on my remote offered Ciphers that is compatible with paramiko (It's not compatible with `aes256-gcm@openssh.com`) :

  ```
    #/etc/ssh/sshd_config remote
    Ciphers aes256-ctr
  ```

Works fine now !

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0